# Why does (+ + '') === 0?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Can anyone please explain this weird javascript behavior?

```
+
// Rightfully gets a syntax error, because there are no operands

+ +
// Same as above

+ + ''
// Interpreted as 0

typeof(+ + '')
// Interpreted as "number"

+ + '' === 0
// Interpreted as true
```

So in other words, (+ + '') is computed as zero.  1) How is that even syntactically allowed?  2) Why does that compute to zero?

Comment: `+` is the unary plus operator, converting something to a number. `+""` is equivalent to `Number("")`, which is `0`

Comment: Operators have specified behavior. Operates operate on operands. JavaScript is loosely typed. When an operator operates on an operand which is a valid operand for the given operator, it will perform its operation with type coercion if needed. So the only question that remains is how particular operators behave when operating on particular types of operands. This is well documented in [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and in numerous other resources on the internet.

Comment: Kinda makes you appreciate strong typing.

Comment: learning the half-dozen confusing comparisons like this is the price we pay to avoid typing every little thing.

Answer (score 7):

The [unary plus (`+`) operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) converts the right hand side to a number.

So you have 0 ← 0 ← *empty string*.

Comment: Shouldn't that be of type string though, since I'm appending an empty string? typeof(0 + '') === "string"

Comment: @carlbenson: There's no appending/concatenation. `+(+(""))` It would be a different story if you had this instead `"" + + ""`, which would be `(""+(+("")))`. See precedence and associativity of JS operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FOperator_Precedence